# finding the number of natural solutions to an equation

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

i need to find the number of solutions to the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3=14$ in positive integers $x_1 \le 3, x_2 \le 4, x_3 \le 8$.

According to the lessons I think I need to introduce a new variable, $y$, but then when I do that I get a negative.
$$
y_1=x_1−3 \\
y_2=x_2−4 \\
y_3=x_3−8
$$
i cant seem to find the problem why this is happening.. or what i need to do more
thanks for any help and tips!

Comment: Isn't it $x_1\ge 3$? and so on?

Comment: hello guys , i just rechecked and it is x1≤3

Comment: My **newbie** approach to questions like this is the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, I just do it on autopilot so I'm not sure if it's the best solution here. Just wanted to point it out. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did is good, if you want to work with nonnegative values you might very well do:

$y_1=3-x_1,\quad y_2=4-x_2,\quad  y_3=8-x_3$

So $y_1,y_2,y_3\ge 0$, and

$y_1+y_2+y_3=15-(x_1+x_2+x_3)=1$

Which happens only when two $y$'s are $0$ and the third is $1$